# Rate of convergence conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given a convergent sequence $(x_k)$ does it suffice that
$$|x_{k+1}|\le C|x_k|+o(|x_k|)$$
definitively, with $|C|<1$ to state that the rate of convergence of $(x_k)$ is less than $C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume $x_k\to0$, then the [rate of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) can be estimated as follows:

$$
\lim \frac{|x_{k+1}|}{|x_k|}
\le \lim \frac{C|x_k|+\mathrm o(|x_k|)}{|x_k|}
= C+\underbrace{\lim \frac{\mathrm o(|x_k|)}{|x_k|}}_{\to\,0\,\text{by assumption}}=C
$$

So you can conclude that it is less *or equal* $C$. You cannot do better because $x_n=C^n$ would be a counter-example (here $\mathrm o(|x_k|)=0$).